# Is it possible to convert .edmx to bak file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I run into one problem and I have no idea what to do.
The scenario is followong. I have application which is done in `EntityFramework` using `Database First Approach` and I have .edmx file store in my Model folder. Right now  I want to deploy this application but I can not  deploy database since I don't see it.
In my WebServer doesn't support .edmx file to be inserted only way is to use `.bak` file.
Can someone tell me and suggestio me what to do ? And what is the best way to deploy database or even Is it possible oto convert this .edmx to .bak file ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.
If you are using migrations you can use that mechanism to create your database.